# Get current time in LogiQL

Tags: logicblox, logiql

How can I get the specific date and time that a logic file is being executed in LogiQL?

What I want essentially is a way to pinpoint the unique time a certain logic is being processed by the engine, in order to use this time as a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in `datetime:now[]` gives you the time of the beginning of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a unique identifier for a particular transaction, you might also be interested in transaction:id[], which gives you exactly that.